# Save short-circurt current data to CSV using python in PSS/E program

Tags: python, csv, psse

I am studying students in the power system and I want to use python in PSS/E program. I can use python in PSS/E program to run short-circuit current data. But I don't know how to use python to save short circuit current data to CSV. l can create one CSV file now , but I don't know how to write data to CSV.

I use psse ver34 & python 2.7.

I have this small code:

```py
import os, math, time
sqrt3 = math.sqrt(3.0)
sbase = 100.0     # MVA

str_time = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_", time.localtime())
fnamout  = str_time + 'short_circuit_in_line_slider.csv'
fnamout  = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),fnamout)
foutobj  = open(fnamout,'w')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pssarrays` module written by the PSSE developers to perform ASCC and read the results all within python, i.e., outside the GUI.  You can view the documentation as follows:

```
import psse34
import pssarrays

help(pssarrays.ascc_currents)
```

After you have loaded the case in python memory and defined your subsystem (e.g., by using `psspy.bsys()`) for which to apply faults you can run ASCC as follows:

```
robj = pssarrays.ascc_currents(
    sid=0,    # this could be different for you
    flt3ph=1, # you may wish to apply different faults
)
```

and process the results as follows:

```
with open('your_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for bus_number, sc_results in zip(robj.fltbus, robj.flt3ph.values()):
        f.write('{},{}\n'.format(bus_number, sc_results['ia1']))
```

which will write the positive sequence currents *ia1* to a file; you may wish to have different data written to the file.  Please read the docstring, i.e., `help(pssarrays.ascc_currents)`, otherwise none of this will make sense.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question. If only bus 2 fault in a system , can I use `pssarrays.ascc_currents` to see the contribution current of other buses?
I only know
 `robj = pssarrays.ascc_currents(
    rprtyp  = 2 or 3      
    rprlvl  = 2       # number of contribution levels
) `
But how do I save these data in csv one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file.write` to write data to a file

Use 'a' to append to a given file. Use the `with` statement to guarantee the file will be closed when you are done.

```py
with open(fnameout, 'a') as file:
    file.write(DATA + "\n")
```